# Why is this Option transformed to a String? [Scala]

Tags: scala, functional-programming, language-features, pattern-matching

I'm still a Scala noob, and this confuses me:

```
import java.util.regex._

object NumberMatcher {
  def apply(x:String):Boolean = {
    val pat = Pattern.compile("\\d+")
    val matcher = pat.matcher(x)
    return matcher.find
  }

  def unapply(x:String):Option[String] = {
    val pat = Pattern.compile("\\d+")
    val matcher = pat.matcher(x)
    if(matcher.find) {
      return Some(matcher.group())
    }
    None
  }
}

object x {
  def main(args : Array[String]) : Unit = {
    val strings = List("geo12","neo493","leo")
    for(val string <- strings) {
      string match {
        case NumberMatcher(group) => println(group)
        case _ => println ("no")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I wanted to add pattern matching for strings containing digits ( so I can learn more about pattern matching ), and in `unapply` I decided to return a `Option[String]`. However, in the println in the NumberMatcher case, `group` is seen as a String and not as an `Option`. Can you shed some light? The output produced when this is ran is:

`12,493,no`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [this example](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/112).

The `unapply` method returns `Some value` if it succeeded in extracting one, otherwise `None`. So internally the

```
case NumberMatcher(group) => println(group)
```

invokes `unapply` and looks whether it returns *some value*. If it does, we already have to true result and therefore no `Option` type remains. The pattern matching extracts the returned value from the *option*.

Comment: So `unapply` can only return an `Option` type? It can't return a String directly?

Comment: right. unapply can't return a String directly. If it did, how would you indicate that the pattern didn't match.

Comment: Unapply methods can return a boolean in which case the match block's case clause uses an empty pattern parameter list.